# Amazon Lex Error: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the PutIntent operation: RelativeId does not match Lex ARN format

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

I'm trying to build a chatbot using Amazon's `boto3` library. Right now, I am trying to create an intent using the `put_intent` function. My code is as follows:

```
intent = lexClient.put_intent(name = 'test',                                 
                              sampleUtterances = ["Who is messi?"]  
                              )
```

When I try running this, I get the following exception:

> botocore.errorfactory.BadRequestException: An error occurred
>   (BadRequestException) when calling the PutIntent operation: RelativeId
>   does not match Lex ARN format: intent:test2:$LATEST

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error when trying to have a digit in intent name field. Realized that was not allowed when trying to do the same from AWS console.

Error handling could really be more specific.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Bots, Intents, and Slot types can only have letters and non-consecutive underscores.

Answer (score 3):

Try taking the question mark out of the utterance, that has caused me issues in the past!

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you so much!!

Comment: No worries! Would you mind marking the answer as correct? It does seem a bit bizarre that the character which breaks utterances is the question mark character!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run GetSlotType. That will return current checksum for that slot. Put that checksum in your PutSlotType checksum. Big bang boom.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexModelBuildingService.html#getSlotType-property

var params = {
    name: "AppointmentTypeValue",
    checksum:'54c6ab5f-fe30-483a-a364-b76e32f6f05d',

```
description: "Type of dentist appointment to schedule'",
enumerationValues: [
    {
        value: "cleaning"
    },
    {
        value: "whitening"
    },
    {
        value: "root canal"
    },
    {
        value:"punch my face"
    }
]
```

};

Answer (score 0):

For the `put_intent` function I faced similar issues.
At least the following 3 are worth mentioning.

1. Sample Utterances

There are requirements for the sample utterances:

> An utterance can consist only of Unicode
> characters, spaces, and valid punctuation marks. Valid punctuation
> marks are: periods for abbreviations, underscores, apostrophes, and
> hyphens. If there is a slot placeholder in your utterance, ensure that
> it's in the {slotName} format and has spaces at both ends.

It seems like there is no error raised when calling the `put_intent` function with the following code.

```
intent = lexClient.put_intent(name = 'test',                                 
                              sampleUtterances = ["Who is messi"]  
                              )
```

However, if you try to add it to your bot and start building the bot it will fail.

To fix it remove the question mark at the end of you sampleUtterance.

```
intent = lexClient.put_intent(name = 'test',                                 
                              sampleUtterances = ["Who is messi?"]  
                              )
```

2. Prior intent version

If your intent already exists you need to add the `checksum` to your function call. To get the checksum of your intent you can use the `get_intent` function.

For example [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lex-models.html#LexModelBuildingService.Client.get_intent):

```
response = client.get_intent(
    name='test',
    version='$LATEST'
)
found_checksum = response.get('checksum')
```

After that you can put a new version of the intent:

```
intent = lexClient.put_intent(name = 'test',                                 
                              sampleUtterances = ["Who is messi"],
                              checksum = found_checksum
                              )
```

3. Intent Name (correct in your case, just adding this for reference)

It seems like the `name` can only contain letters, underscores, and should be <=100 in length. Haven't found anything in the docs. This is just trial and error.
Calling `put_intent` with the following:

```
intent = lexClient.put_intent(name = 'test_1',                                 
                              sampleUtterances = ["Who is messi"]  
                              )
```

Results in the following error:

```
BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the PutIntent operation: RelativeId does not match Lex ARN format: intent:test_1:$LATEST
```

To fix the `name` you can replace it to:

```
intent = lexClient.put_intent(name = 'test',                                 
                              sampleUtterances = ["Who is messi"]  
                              )
```